# What language is the music in NieR:Replicant?

Tags: game-music-identification, nier-replicant-1.22474487139, nier

NieR:Replicant's lyrics seem to be written in French/Latin, but I can't quiet pinpoint what language the music is in.
Any thoughts on what languages it could be ?

Comment: [Same question _(and I assume, answer)_ for the sequel](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/304030/what-language-is-the-musics-lyrics-in)

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft It is the same answer. The accept answer even has a quote stating "Its an invented language, *same with the OST of NieR 1*."

Answer (score 3):

According to [an interview on the Playstation Blog](https://blog.playstation.com/2020/12/18/nier-replicant-singer-emi-evans-talks-music-chaos-language-and-more/), NieR Replicant's lyrics are written in a made-up language named "Chaos Language" that was created by Replicant's signer Emi Evans.

> **Perhaps one of its most unique details was the made-up lyrics Emi created, suitably named “Chaos Language”**, invented to sound as if our modern languages had drifted away for thousands of years to finally become indistinguishable to us. “The reason we went for this mysterious made-up language is because we felt that as game music, having lyrics which you can recognize and understand might distract you from the gameplay,” explained Yoko Taro, the game’s director, when I met him in 2017 ahead of the launch of Nier’s sequel, Nier:Automata.
>
> <sub>**Source**: PlayStation Blog - [NieR Replicant singer Emi Evans talks music, Chaos Language, and more](https://blog.playstation.com/2020/12/18/nier-replicant-singer-emi-evans-talks-music-chaos-language-and-more/)</sub>

The same fictional "Chaos Language" was also used for [several songs in NieR: Automata](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/304030/what-language-is-the-musics-lyrics-in).

I recommend reading [the full interview with Emi Evans](https://blog.playstation.com/2020/12/18/nier-replicant-singer-emi-evans-talks-music-chaos-language-and-more/), as she explains the specific languages that inspired Song of the Ancients, Grandma, The Wretched Automatons, and Kainé.

Comment: It's not just NieR: Replicant that uses Chaos language, it's also used for nearly all vocals in NieR: Automata.  The exception is the song Weight of the World which in addition to Chaos language has English and Japanese versions.  It's possible that NieR: [Re]incarnation also uses Chaos language, but I haven't played that one yet.

Comment: The song "Weight of the World" is featured in three languages: Japanese,  English and French. There are however some hard copy versions of the game which don't have French (don't quote me on that).